# Maximize font size based on height

Tags: html, css, font-size

I'm trying to render text as large as possible to fit inside a div, based on width and height of the div. The width-part is already working, but I'm having trouble with the height. Especially 'low' characters like 'y', 'g', 'q' are rendered outside of the parent element.

This fiddle will hopefully clarify what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/xvp7jgy1/6/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>Country</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0012;
  font-size: 60px; /* same as height */
}
```

I would like all text to be shown inside the boundaries of the parent element.

UPDATE:

The dimensions of the div are not always the same as this example, so the solution should be flexible to fit other dimensions.

Comment: play with the line-height of the div e.g. try `0.9`

Comment: yes.. you can try line-height.

Comment: Use padding instead of height

Comment: If you have dynamic heights and widths of the parent element, you could use a script like http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

With vh you can size elements to be the size of the viewport. Maybe it will work.

```
enter code here

div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0012;
}

span {
  font-size: 4vh;
}
```

Comment: As OP mentioned height will be dynamic. This solution won't work at all.

Comment: Okay, sorry I diden't see that.

Answer (score 0):

A block-level element which is `div` over-here by default takes the width of browser and `height` as `0px` till it doesn't have any child element with assigned styling. But as per your above codes you have styling width and height properties for div, so I suggest you to remove that, as your `divs` always going to have text, thus it align your text properly because parent inherits the height from child or content present inside `parent div`. At-present it `overflows some text` because of fixed `height 60px`.

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: #ff0012;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Country</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>y, q, g</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You could even change the display of parent div to inline-block to have width same as content.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the span for your  css?

```
span {
background-color: #ff0012;
font-size: 70px;}
```

Your css will follow the size of your text, no matter what..